# Golang API to WPA Supplicant

Tags: go, dbus, wpa-supplicant

I need connect headless IoT device (Raspberry Pi) to Wi-Fi Network. I have custom Linux built using YoctoProject. I don't have **connman** or **Network Manager** installed. There is only WPA Supplicant.
My services are written in Golang.

Call **wpa_cli** is too tricky and not reliable. 
Trying few available packages, I have decided to write my own.
See below in answer.

Comment: Can you create a rest api using this? I want to run a Rest API on PI so that I can change and get all the available Wifi's inside a client.

Answer (score 3):

Answering to my own question...

**wpa-connect** - API for connection Linux device to Wi-Fi Network (Golang)

This package was developed as part of IoT project in order to add Wi-Fi connectivity to headless Raspberry Pi like devices. No need to **connman** or **Network Manager** be installed.
**wpa-connect** communicates with WPA supplicant over D-Bus (linux message bus system).

Github repository
https://github.com/mark2b/wpa-connect

Examples
Connect to Wi-Fi network

```
import wifi "github.com/mark2b/wpa-connect"

if conn, err := wifi.ConnectManager.Connect(ssid, password, time.Second * 60); err == nil {
    fmt.Println("Connected", conn.NetInterface, conn.SSID, conn.IP4.String(), conn.IP6.String())
} else {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Scan for Wi-Fi networks

```
import wifi "github.com/mark2b/wpa-connect"

if bssList, err := wifi.ScanManager.Scan(); err == nil {
    for _, bss := range bssList {
        print(bss.SSID, bss.Signal, bss.KeyMgmt)
    }
}
```

Package released under a MIT license.

Comment: This is not a place for advertising your own code (even though it might be useful), especially not as an answer to your own question and without any mentioning that this is your code.